# need to implement rails association for sharing same functionalities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have following models and their associations as follows

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :branches

  validates :region_name, presence: true
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region

  validates :branch_name, presence: true
  validates :branch_name, uniqueness: true
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
  has_many :services

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  after_save :toggle_services, if: :status_changed?

  def toggle_services
    self.services.each do |service|
        service.update_attributes!(status: self.status)
    end
  end
end
```

a company can have multiple regions and branches. There is a scenario where in a company with multiple branches will be sharing same services the company provides. How this scenario will be implemented.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem yet. It looks like a branch would always get all the services the company provides as there is no distinction yet between whether a company's service is shared with a branch. Or is modelling what I just described as lacking the exact problem you want to have a solution for?

Comment: let's take an example of bank, like a bank has multiple branches but usually they provide same services at every branch, so how this should be done at model level, is there a way to do this via associations.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to reuse every `Service` the `Company` offers, you could simply write a method to access them:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region

  ...

  def services
    region.company.services
  end
end
```

I would refrain from having a direct association (in the rails sense) to the service, as this would allow a `Branch` instance to change (add/remove) the services a company provides.

But I'd add associations between `Company` and `Branch` as the region does look to be a simple join table and having the association would prettify the code:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :company, through: :region

  ...

  delegate :services,
           to: :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
  has_many :branches, through: :regions
  ...
end
```